# How do I make my Tesla coil more powerful?

Tags: tesla-coil

I have built a spark gap Tesla coil.  It performs pretty well, with 20 cm sparks,  but I want it to perform even better.

I use a really cheap mmc that I bought on eBay, and I was wondering if it would help to make a proper mmc out of pulse capacitor series 94 or if there anything else I can do to make it perform better.

Here's a list of everything I used:

- secondary coil: 1200 turns, 3.5 inches wide, 13 inches tall and 30 AWG wire
- capacitor bank/mmc: 18.8 nF. 20 kV
- neon sign transformer: 10 kV, 50 mA, 50 Hz
- primary coil: 6.5 turns, wire diameter 0.27 inches
- static spark gap 0.3 inches

Comment: As I've said before, Tesla coil design and troubleshooting questions really belong on dedicated forums.  I'm voting to close this question (it's also opinion-based) but as a send-off, here's some of the stuff they'll tell you on a Tesla coil board:
Measure your components to find the exact values for C and L and adjust accordingly.
Make sure your spark gap is well designed and is quenching correctly.
Ensure you have enough top capacitance from your toroid (you will almost always be too low).
20cm from a 500W power input is probably close to what you can reasonably expect with a static gap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you name some other sides to ask more basic questions about tesla coils

Comment: It's been a while since I was active in that space.  It looks like the big mailing list (pupman.com) is in a transition period and somewhat inactive.  If you search "tesla coil forum" I'm sure you'll find something.  They will probably have a list of frequently asked questions that might answer your question.

Comment: @EmilAdser Can you add a schematic or something to improve the question?

Comment: unfortunately i am not able to provide pictures on this site, but i saw some videos about ballast, on tesla coils. can a ballast increase the sparks, if so how